# build buttons in pyqt4 runing corresponding python files when click one of them

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to write a program to build two buttons in pyqt4, when click one of them, it will run corresponding python file. but I can only show one button, what is wrong with my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import ef01, ef02, ef03, ef04, ef05, ef06, ef07, ef08, ef09, ef10, ef11, ef12, basement

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupMainWindow(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 410)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    def setupEF01(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(60, 30, 80, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EF01"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runEF01)
    def runEF01(self):
        ef01.GoToPose()
    def setupEF02(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(180, 30, 80, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EF02"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runEF02)
    def runEF02(self):
        ef02.GoToPose()

    def runAll(self):
        self.setupMainWindow(MainWindow)
        self.setupEF01(MainWindow)
        self.setupEF02(MainWindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #MainWindow = QWdget()
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.runAll()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to build a UI with two buttons and when clicking one of them, it can run corresponding python files. But now only EF02 button showed.

It seems that EF01 button is covered by EF02

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating and setting a new GUI (the `centralWidget`) whenever you call both `setupEF01` or `setupEF02`. This will result in "overriding" the existing (if any) "main" central widget of the QMainWindow.
You shouldn't set a `centralWidget` for each button you want, but add it to the existing one instead.

Based on your own code, this is how you should implement it.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupMainWindow(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 410)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QRect(60, 30, 80, 30))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EF01"))
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.runEF01)

        self.pushButton2 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QRect(180, 30, 80, 30))
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EF02"))
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.runEF02)

    def runEF01(self):
        ef01.GoToPose()

    def runEF02(self):
        ef02.GoToPose()

    def runAll(self):
        self.setupMainWindow(MainWindow)
```

That said, it looks like you're trying to write your own code based on the output of `pyuic`, given an UI file saved from Qt Designer, which is simply *wrong*.
You shouldn't even ever look at those files (in fact, it's clearly stated in its header that you should never edit them, while I can understand the confusion).

What you should do, instead, is to create and save your GUI in Designer (if you need to), and then follow the PyQt suggested conduct, as explained [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). It might seem a bit overwhelming, but I can tell you that it's the best way to do it, as using the pyuic output to create your own code (expecially if you are new to Qt) is really not a good approach.